# file_put_contents(): failed to open stream

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I am tring to create drag and drop upload on my webpage. I code which I have written opens the file using Jquery and sends the data using a XHR request to a php file. The php file will then move the file to my perfered location. When i drag and drop my file to the drop area i receved a 200 post request which i think mean data be being sent to my php script but then I recived the following error:

```
file_put_contents(../../../media/SeagateHDD/Uploads/): failed to open stream
```

I belive that this error is becasue php cant find the location(../../../media/SeagateHDD/Uploads/) but I have check ten times and the location is correct with no spelling mistakes. I have also check my permission and owner for the location and everything is correct with owner "www-data:www-data" and permissions "0775" even tred "0777" and nothing works. If anyone could help me fix said people I will be very greatful.

My Javascript

$(function(){

```
var obj = $('#Upload_form');

obj.on('dragover', function(e){
    //prevent browser from open the file when drop off
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border',"3px solid #000000");
});

obj.on('dragleave', function(e){
    //prevent browser from open the file when drop off
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border',"3px dashed #4a4a4a");
});

obj.on('drop',function(e){
    //prevent browser from open the file when drop off
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('border',"3px dashed #4a4a4a");

    //retrieve uploaded files data
    var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var file = files[0];

    upload(file);
});

function upload(file){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //initiate Request
    xhr.open('POST','../PHP/Drop_Upload.php', true);

    //set headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.fileName);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Size',file.fileSize);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.fileType);

    //send the file
    xhr.send(file);
}
});
```

My PHP

```
$string = file_get_contents('php://input');
$path = '../../../media/SeagateHDD/Uploads/';

if ( !file_exists($path) ) {
  mkdir ($path, 0777);
 }

if (file_put_contents($path,$string)==true){
    echo 'File Uploaded Successfully';
}else{
    echo 'File Failed to Upload';
}
```

Comment: file_put_contents needs a $path to a file not a directory. You never specify the file to put $string into.

Answer (score 1):

In $path you are providing directory path.It should provide file path instead. like  $path = '../../../media/SeagateHDD/Uploads/something.txt';

[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert relative path to absolute path this way:

```
$path = realpath('../../../media/SeagateHDD/Uploads/');
```

And after that you have to append the filename where you want to write to, for example:

```
$path .= "text.txt";
```